# How can I show that the leading monomial ideal equals the leading term ideal for some collection of polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

For some collection of polynomials, my goal is to show that the ideal generated by the leading monomials of the collection is equal to the ideal generated by the leading terms of this collection. I understand that for example, if we look at the polynomial $4x^2+3x+1$, the leading term would be $4x^2$ and the leading monomial would be just $x^2$. I also know that clearly the only difference between the leading monomial ideal and the leading term ideal is some constant, but I am unsure how I can make the claim that they are equal. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An ideal of polinomials is closed under product by scalar (in fact, is closed by product with any polynomial, by definition of ideal of a ring). In particular, if $cx^n$ belongs to an ideal, with $c$ constant, then $x^n=c^{-1}cx^n$ also belongs to the ideal and vice versa

Comment: The previous comment basically answers the question, but it's worth noting that this entire discussion is implicitly taking place over a field. If we consider the same question over $\mathbb Z$, we of course have a strict inclusion $(4x^2) \subsetneq (x^2)$.